# Auto-type conversion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

The following all expressions in JavaScript are far obvious.

```
var x = 10 + 10;
```

The value of `x` is `20`.

```
x = 10 + '10';
```

The value of `x` in this case is `1010` because the `+` operator is overloaded. If any of the operands is of type string, string concatenation is made and if all the operands are numbers, addition is performed.

```
x = 10 - 10;
x = 10 - '10';
```

In both of these cases, the value of `x` will be `0` because the `-` operator is not overloaded in that way and all operands are converted to numbers, if they are not before the actual subtraction is performed (you may clarify, if anyway I'm wrong).

---

What happens in the following expression.

```
x = '100' - -'150';
```

The value of `x` is `250`. Which also appears to be obvious but this expression somewhat appears to be the equivalent to the following expression.

```
x = '100' +'150';
```

If it had been the case then these two strings would have been concatenated and assigned `100150` to `x`. So why is addition performed in this case?

---

**EDIT :**

`+'10' + 5` returns `15` and `'a' + + 'b'` returns `aNaN`. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Fiddle created http://jsfiddle.net/WPUzh/ `- -` might be the same as `+` in mathematics, but i doubt the parser for the javascript is written like this

Comment: Even if JS simplified the expression before doing anything (which I doubt it does), it just wouldn't make sense for it to turn `minus minus` into `concatentate` rather than `plus`

Comment: In order to avoid such bizarre craziness, never ever do math with strings... `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()` are awesome, use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case `- -` is not evaluated first to become equivalent to `+`. `-"150"` is evaluated as a number, and so became `-150`.

As you can't subtract a string (`NaN`), JS then take `"100"` and make a number, and then it run `100` - `-150` which is 250.

The key is really that you can't subtract type string, so it converts those strings to numbers.

Comment: `+'10' + 5` returns `15` and `'a' + + 'b'` returns `aNaN`. Do you know why?

Comment: Yeah, entity are looked first. So `+'10'` is `10` after type convertion. `+'b'` try to convert `b` to positive number, but it is `NaN`. Tean `+` operator is taken as a concatenation operator as `'a'` is a string, becaming `'a' + NaN`, `aNaN`

Comment: Yeah, really got it! I don't plan to use such expressions but just wanted to know about them as they exist. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The + and - operators respond differently to strings.

The + operator concatenates strings; however, the - operator does not do the reverse (split strings).

So if JavaScript sees `'100' +'150'`, it thinks "Hey, I see strings with a +... I can concatenate them."

If JS sees `'100' - -'150'`, it thinks, "Hey, I see strings with a - .. i can't really do any string functions, so I'll treat them as numbers..."

Comment: `+'10' + 5` returns `15` and `'a' + + 'b'` returns `aNaN`. Do you know why?

Answer (score 2):

The unary `-` operator always converts its operand to Number (ECMA-262 s. 11.4.6). So

```
x = '100' - -'150';
```

is equivalent to

```
x = '100' - -150;
```

which reduces further to

```
x = 100 - -150;
```

because the binary `-` operator also always converts its operands to Number (s. 11.6.2).

By contrast, the unary `+` operator converts its operands to strings if either one is already a string (s. 11.6.1).

You can find the complete spec for ECMAscript (and therefore for the core of Javascript) at http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm.

Comment: `+'10' + 5` returns `15` and `'a' + + 'b'` returns `aNaN`. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

If JS sees minus operator used on a string it firstly tries to type cast it to number and then evaluates expression because Minus operator is used only for arithmetical operations.
Plus operator could mean in first place concatenation and then addition.

In some other weakly typed languages like PHP this ambiguity is eliminated by using two different operators for concatenation and addition.

However the proper way to use arithmetic on strings is to type cast them manually to numbers (using [parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)).

Comment: `+'10' + 5` returns `15` and `'a' + + 'b'` returns `aNaN`. Do you know why?

Comment: Because 'a' and 'b' are properly defined strigns that are Not a Number typed (NaN). JS concatenates 'a' with 'b' but 'b' is already typecasted (NaN) - the result is the string 'aNaN'. If you want to add variables 'a' and 'b' using a sting like this "a+b" you can use EVAL("a+b"). However I do not reccomend using eval() for any purpose. Just make sure you are working with data types you want by manually casting them if needed.

Answer (score 1):

### Addendum

This table shows the result of various conversions where variable `s=string` and `n=number`. You can also try your own values using the provided code snippet.

This thread answered some questions I had. And so I'm posting my test results to help others who arrive here looking for answers.

```
╔═════════════╦═══════════╦════════╗
║ INPUT       ║ VALUE     ║ TYPEOF ║
╠═════════════╬═══════════╬════════╣
║ n           ║ 11.5      ║ number ║
║ s           ║ -1.5      ║ string ║
║ s - 0       ║ -1.5      ║ number ║
║ n + s - 0   ║ NaN       ║ error  ║
║ n + (s - 0) ║ 10        ║ number ║
║ s + 0       ║ -1.50     ║ string ║
║ n + s + 0   ║ 11.5-1.50 ║ string ║
║ n + (s + 0) ║ 11.5-1.50 ║ string ║
║ n + s       ║ 11.5-1.5  ║ string ║
║ s + n       ║ -1.511.5  ║ string ║
║ +s + n      ║ 10        ║ number ║
║ n + +s      ║ 10        ║ number ║
║ n++s        ║           ║ error  ║
║ n+(+s)      ║ 10        ║ number ║
║ Number(s)+n ║ 10        ║ number ║
╚═════════════╩═══════════╩════════╝
```

```js
var n = 11.5, s = '-1.5';

add('n');
add('s');
add('s - 0');
add('n + s - 0');
add('n + (s - 0)');
add('s + 0');
add('n + s + 0');
add('n + (s + 0)');
add('n + s');
add('s + n');
add('+s + n');
add('n + +s');
add('n++s');
add('n+(+s)');
add('Number(s) + n');

function add(eq) {
 var v, r, t;
  try { v = eval(eq); t = typeof v; } catch(e) { v = ''; t = 'error';}
  if (t=='number' && isNaN(v)) t = 'error';
  r = window.stdout.insertRow();
  r.className = t;
  r.insertCell().innerHTML = eq;
  r.insertCell().innerHTML = v;
  r.insertCell().innerHTML = t;
}
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; font-family: sans-serif; }
td { min-width: 5em; padding: 2px; border: 1px dimgray solid; text-align: right; }
tr {   background-color: lightgreen; }
.string { background-color: lightyellow; }
.error { background-color: pink; }
```

```html
<table id="stdout"><caption>Type Conversion Results</caption></table>
```