# JavaScript expression explanation

Tags: javascript

```js
console.log("1" - - "1" );
```

Why does the code give me the folloing output: `2`

Comment: because if you substract javascript converts your strings to numbers for you.

Comment: What did you expect the result to be?

Comment: String to Number type coercion. Perhaps parenthesis will shed some light `(1 - (-1))`

Comment: "one minus minus one", which is algebraically the same as "one plus one".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just two strings being cast as numbers and subtracted. Essentially:

1 - -1

Or 2.

```js
console.log(1 - - 1); 
console.log("1" - - "1");
```

for reference 
[Auto-type conversion in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982114/auto-type-conversion-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

this string is equivalent to

```
1 - (-1)
```

since javascript converts the string to numbers for you try running the code snippet

```js
console.log(- "1");
console.log(1 - "1");
console.log(1 - - "1");
console.log("1" - - "1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you subtract -1 from 1 you get 2, simple math, and that's what JavaScript does too.

JavaScript converts the strings you give it into numbers and then runs the calculation.

```js
console.log(1 - - 1);
console.log(1 - - 2); 
console.log(1 - - 3);
console.log(1 - - 155);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another explanation besides the ones above is that JS has 'forced type conversion', and your expression is essentially trying to subtract a string from another string.

Try a method that converts the strings to numbers so you have more control over the type conversion and the output is more in-line with what you're expecting.