# Why can I do math with Date objects?

Tags: javascript

When I subtract two Date-objects like this:

```
const startTime = new Date();
await someAsyncStuff();
const endTime = new Date();

const elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
console.log(`The async stuff took ${elapsedTime} ms`);
```

Why does the Date objects end up being cast to milliseconds, which are then subtracted? I understand that they do, but I can't figure out what the actual sequence of events is that lead to this.

Comment: because javascript was first implemented on windows - would be microseconds if it had been linux :)

Comment: you can use `.getTime()` which will transform the date into miliseconds and then you can make the `-` operation. also, `await is only valid in async function` so you should make a self invoking function like `(async () => {
    await yourFunction()
})();` to call the await

Comment: Thanks @MihaiT - I meant the above as pseudo code. I was actually looking for the answer to why I can do math with the actual Date instances (why I can subtract them without calling `getTime()`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's how javascript does [automatic type conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982114/auto-type-conversion-in-javascript) - just like arithmetic operations (that you are performing here). You were lucky that you subtracted, if you've added them you'd end up with a string holding two date strings in a row because of how `toPrimitive` (that gets called implicitly) works for Dates. Consider the following

```js
// automatic casting
console.log("1" - "1"); // 0
// but
console.log("1" + "1"); // 11

// now with dates
// automatic casting
console.log(new Date() - new Date()); 0
console.log(new Date() + new Date()); // Mon Jun 11 2018 10:10:36 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)Mon Jun 11 2018 10:10:36 GMT+0200 (Mitteleuropäische Sommerzeit)
```

The specification on the [additional operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) has the following hint that explains this further

> All native ECMAScript objects except **Date objects** handle the absence of a hint as if the hint Number were given; Date objects handle the absence of a hint **as if the hint String** were given.

JavaScript converts your value to a primitive when using arithmetic opererators, the method that gets called here is

```
Date.prototype [ @@toPrimitive ] ( hint )
```

> [**Date.prototype [ @@toPrimitive ] ( hint )**](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype-@@toprimitive)
>   This function is called by ECMAScript language operators to convert a Date object to a primitive value. The allowed values for hint are "default", "number", and "string". Date objects, are unique among built-in ECMAScript object in that they treat "default" as being equivalent to "string", All other built-in ECMAScript objects treat "default" as being equivalent to "number".

That said. The reason why your code works how it works is the later auto conversion performed by the [subtraction](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.3), which gives hint to `toPrimitive` to return a number.

Comment: Woah, I didn't know that!

Comment: Also another good spec link: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype-@@toprimitive

Comment: I believe this is what happens, yeah @Steve

Comment: I'll accept this one as the "correct answer", but both this and @Steve's answer are spot on here. Thanks for the great job explaining this

Comment: I believe so too @KrisSelbekk. Thanks for the interesting question!

Comment: Thank you @T.J.Crowder - is it really the subtraction that gives a hint to `toPrimitive`, or is subtraction actually causing another type conversion (I don't think the later is the case, cause it would already be a string which is returned from toPrimitve)?

Answer (score 6):

In general, JavaScript objects can define methods to convert the object to a String or a number (which you can customize by defining `toString` and `valueOf` methods). JavaScript will use those methods in numerical contexts (like `2 * a`) or string contexts (like `'' + a`) to convert the object to the appropriate primitive.

In a context where it's ambiguous whether to use numerical or string conversion (like `a + b`), there's a default behavior, depending on the type of the object. Interestingly, `Date` are singled out among the default ECMAScript objects to convert to a String, instead of a number. Via [the spec](https://262.ecma-international.org/6.0/#sec-date.prototype-@@toprimitive):

> Date objects, are unique among built-in ECMAScript object in that they
> treat "**`default`**" as being equivalent to "**`string`**", All other built-in
> ECMAScript objects treat "**`default`**" as being equivalent to "**`number`**".

In the particular case of `Date` objects, the [numerical conversion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) (the `valueOf` method) converts the time to epoch milliseconds, while the [string conversion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) (the `toString` method) converts the object to a human-readable string. As [@baao mentions in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50793100/6184972), this can cause some issues when doing "arithmetic" with objects, due to automatic conversions of type.

In summary, `Date` (unlike most other objects) defaults to string conversion, but since subtraction requires two numbers for it to make sense, it converts the dates to numbers.

It's generally a good idea to explicitly define the behavior, in this case using `valueOf`, `getTime` or `toString` to make the code less ambiguous.

For more information of whether JavaScript chooses to use `toString` vs `valueOf`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485632/valueof-vs-tostring-in-javascript), [the overall spec for addition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) (and [subtraction](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.2)), and [the specific spec for Dates](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype-@@toprimitive) ([mdn link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/@@toPrimitive)), and [@baao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50793100/6184972) for a more in depth look.

See Also:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf

Comment: But it doesn't work the same way when you use the `+` operand - is string concatenation considered more important than arithmetic?

Comment: Can you please point me to the part of the spec that does undermine that? I don't believe this answer is correct ( I really don't know though and would like to learn ). If it were, adding the both dates would yield a date in the year 4036 but it doesn't

Comment: Perhaps `toString` is called before `valueOf` in the case of the overloaded plus operator?

Comment: I believe it's the casting only, but I'm already studying the spec to find out for sure @KrisSelbekk

Comment: I believe it depends on the context-- it looks like by default it uses a String context, but you can change it to a number context, like +(new Date())

Comment: Yeah exactly. Just like explained with auto casting - I believe the correct answer would be a combination of yours and mine. Still searching though

Comment: I found this answer to be particularly instructive: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2486760/6184972 There's a link to spec if you're interested: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1

Comment: See the quote I posted from the spec. If it were because of valueOf (which returns a number as you've correctly said), the hint wouldn't be necessary I guess.

Answer (score 2):

It equals `endTime.getTime() - startTime.getTime()`

As you say, they cast to millisecond and that exactly shows the difference.

Comment: But how does the JavaScript engine know to call getTime() on these objects? Is it a hard-coded special case?

Comment: The same way you can do `15 - "5"` and get 10

Comment: Because Date object is created by them, they do Date's minus operator that way and I think it really should be that way.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because JS asks for the primitive of the Date's object when performing such operation, through the method [valueOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf). The Date's object [overrides `valueOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) methods, so that the value used is basically the same of [getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime).

You can also try by yourself:

```
const o = { valueOf: () => 10 };

console.log(o + 1) // 11
```